# Мониторинг сетевой карты С++ linux

Tags: c++, linux, c

Необходимо мониторить суммарный объем данных проходящих через сетевую карту, как такое делать на в linux используя c++ ??

Comment: C и ++ — это необходимость?

Answer (score 2):

Например http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getifaddrs.3.html или http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/netdevice.7.html через ioctl.

Или надергать из sysfs через файлы

```
cat /sys/class/net/eth0/statistics/rx_bytes
cat /sys/class/net/eth0/statistics/rx_packets

cat /sys/class/net/eth0/statistics/tx_packets
cat /sys/class/net/eth0/statistics/tx_bytes
```

Answer (score 1):

Установите `qtchooser`. потом запустите `qdbusviewer`. перейдите во вкладку `system bus`. найдите `org.freedesktop.NetworkManager`. найдите то что на скриншоте. подключитесь к шине, к сигналу. и на каждой смене скорости получайте значения. [image: dbus]

Comment: refreshrate стоит нулем если мы не в иксах, надо её установить. сигнал на проперти ченжед, а не на скорость

Comment: но лучше вешаться на орг.фридесктоп.дбас.пропертис - сигнал внутри сервиса деприкатед